# Can I create Webpart in Java and deploy it to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: web-part

Can I create Webpart in Java and deploy it to SharePoint 2010? What basics needs?

Comment: You can use Javascript.. but that's not the same now is it. Also, you can use Iframes if you really needed to display some java controls.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted.. although it may be obvious to others it is still a legit question.

Comment: +1 there is no need for the downvote just because they asked a real legit question that not everyone would know! give the guy a break!

Comment: Why is the answer not yes? "A special kind of web part known as App Part takes care of embedding the App's page into the hosted page. " http://ctp-ms.blogspot.com/2012/12/interoperability-between-java-and.html

Comment: App parts and webparts are different things... App part is just an iFrame, whereas OP is asking if he can develop a webpart in java or not, and the answer is no. Your referenced article is different then what OP asked for.

Comment: And not applicable for 2010 as the question states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Steve said, you can't create a webpart using Java language for SharePoint framework and I don't think there should be any need for it either, its more like you want to play games developed for "Play Station 3" on "Xbox-360" anyway I find out that there are few ways you can show java portlets in SharePoint webparts using Web Services for Remote Portlets if that helps.

You can read more about it on [this Microsoft's blog](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=537) or simply download WSRP toolkit released by Microsoft.

I also find few useful links that might help you for what you are trying to achieve,

[How to access sharepoint document library through JAVA API](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/1340c82a-825b-4a92-a20e-1ae0dd1023d2/)

[How to show java portlets in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995039/how-to-show-java-portlets-in-sharepoint)

[Using a Java applet in a SharePoint web part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348159/using-a-java-applet-in-a-sharepoint-web-part)

Oh and one thing I forgot to mention and that is Webpart is a ASP.NET control and is also rendered by asp.net (dunno if you know or not but sharepoint is developed on top of ASP.Net) so you can't develop it in Java as you won't going to have access to parent classes if I make any sense.

Hope it helps, but if you have some specific requirements let us know and we will try to help you accordingly as much as we could.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, SharePoint is based on .Net and then requires you to build .Net apps (C#, VB.net or any cls compliant language)

Comment: ok but how about if i could prepare the .dll from java and provide it with xml alias and define it as safe control ? I this that should work. isn't it ?

Comment: no it won't. Java product bytecode interpreted by the JVM (Java Virtual Machine). .Net produce MSIL assemblies ran by the CLR (Common language Runtime). They are simply not compatible. It's not a SharePoint specific problem, but a wider language interoperability compatibility. To illustrate the dead end, imagine you want to create a WebPart, you will have to inherits `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart` class. Do you think it's possible with a java code?